# Angular JS pagination not showing the correct number

Tags: html, angularjs, pagination

I am using angular js pagination. The problem with my pagination is showing one number extra forexample if I have 25 total records it will say 
**showing 1-26 of 25 records** . How do I fix it I tried to search from where it gets fixed. my code looks like this

```
$scope.gridOptions1 = {
  paginationPageSizes: [15,25,50, 75],
  paginationPageSize: 15,
  useExternalPagination: true,
  enableFiltering: true,
  columnDefs: [
    {name:'serviceId',enableCellEdit:false, sort: { direction: 'desc', priority: 0 }},
    {name:'startover',displayName:"Action",enableCellEdit:false,cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;"><a ng-click="grid.appScope.del(row.entity)">Delete</a></div>'}
  ]
};
```

Comment: Do you have 25 records as in 0 to 25? ;-)

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: Are you using this plugin module ? http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.pagination.directive:uiGridPagination

Comment: no its not counting from 0. if total records are 7 it shows showing 1 to 8 out of 7

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan yes exactly the same. even on the examples of this link its showing 11-12 of 13 records

Comment: Yes seems like a bug, in the plugin. Need to do a walk-through across the their code and see :D

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan Is there any other plugin that can be used instead of this one?